# What's wrong with this JavaScript sample?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
a.onkeydown = function() {
    if (a.value.match("hi")) {
        a.value.replace("hi", "span style='color:red;'>hi</span>");
    }
};

<input type="text" id="myInput" />
```

It does not take any action to replace 'hi' with a red 'hi'.

Comment: You asked 10 questions and didn't accept any answer yet. Please confirm that you do understand the concept of accepting answers.... if you know how to respond to comments, that is. `:)` ("add comment" below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using variable `a` which is not declared anywhere, I assume you mean `input`
2. A better option would be to use `onkeyup` which will trigger the event as soon as you type `hi`
3. After you do the replace you need to assign it to something.
4. Make sure the `<script/>` is after the element so the element is ready in the dom.

Putting that all together you get this:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var input = document.getElementById("myInput");

    input.onkeyup = function() {
      if (input.value.match("hi")) {
      input.value = input.value.replace("hi", "<span style='color:red;'>hi</span>");
    }
};
</script>
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/YnLV5/).**

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're leaving something out, the variable `a` doesn't represent your textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the opening < before the span, for one. Also, I don't know if you can nest HTML inside an input element. A better way would be to turn on a class/style that makes the text red if the value == 'hi'.